# How to Copy data from an Access Database opening in read only

Tags: database, ms-access, permissions

I have an access database in 97 and I am just trying to open it in access 03.

I can open it and see the data. but it is read only therefore I can't do anything with the data, not even copy.

I need to make sure the data matches a 2003 version of this database that was converted.

In order to do this, I take all the data in the tables from the 97 access file, and compare it to the data in the 03 tables. with a copy-paste into a textbox within a small application I built. Or I would export the 97 table -> create the same table in the new 03 database -> then import and compare again, to make sure everything imported fine.

However, I can't do ANYTHING because of it being read only.

Things I have tried:

- Checked off the read only attribute from the folder
- Looked at the actual access file permissions to make sure my account had modify/read/write which it does
- searched online and found most cases to be the fault of the permissions.

is there anyway I can just copy the 97 data somehow? This database has thousands of records, and I would really prefer to not to look at each one individually and check it in the 03 database.

Comment: Import the data into a new database. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-HA001227658.aspx

Comment: It appears I don't have any more licensed copies of the 03 access. So is there another plausible workaround?

Comment: You can't open MS Access 2003 and perform those steps?

Comment: Unfortunately not, considering that MS Access 2003 is not activated(we used all the licenses already), I am unable to create a fresh DB. I can modify DB's though.

Comment: I found another key and was able to import the data into a new database after uninstalling/reinstalling office. so Now I can do what I originally wanted to. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Sorry I couldn't have been of more assistance.